# How to add custom template in plugin?

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template

I want to add a custom template for a custom post (`'post_type' => 'matches'`).

I am writing a plugin.I keep my template in the `templates/fp-fixture-template.php` file.

Here is the function:

```
function fixture_template( $template_path ) { 
    if ( get_post_type() == 'matches' ) {
        if ( is_single() ) { 
            // checks if the file exists in the theme first,
            // otherwise serve the file from the plugin 
            if ( $theme_file = locate_template( array ( 'fp-fixture-template.php' ) ) ) { 
                $template_path = $theme_file; 
            } else { 
                $template_path = plugin_dir_path( FILE ) 
                    . 'templates/fp-fixture-template.php'; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    return $template_path; 
}
```

Here is the filter:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'fixture_template');
```

Code in the `fp-fixture-template.php` file:

```
<?php
 /*Template Name: Matches Template
 */
 if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Don't allow direct access
?>
<div id="primary">
    <div id="content" role="main">
    <?php
    $mypost = array( 'post_type' => 'matches', );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $mypost );
    ?>
    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>> 
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>      
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

This plugin looks for `page_contact.php` from active theme's folder and uses plugin's `templates/page_contact.php` as a fallback.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Test Plugin
 */

add_filter( 'template_include', 'contact_page_template', 99 );

function contact_page_template( $template ) {
    $file_name = 'page_contact.php';

    if ( is_page( 'contact' ) ) {
        if ( locate_template( $file_name ) ) {
            $template = locate_template( $file_name );
        } else {
            // Template not found in theme's folder, use plugin's template as a fallback
            $template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/templates/' . $file_name;
        }
    }

    return $template;
}
```

Create page "Contact" and then `templates/page_contact.php` in your plugins folder. Now you should see your template content instead of normal template.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do that?Or Could you please share your code?

Comment: okay I added this code in my template file but shows no page found??<pre> <?php
/*Template Name: Matches Template
 */
?>
<div id="primary">
    <div id="content" role="main">
        <?php
        $mypost = array( 'post_type' => 'matches', );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $mypost );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>> 
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>      
</div></pre>

Comment: is_page or is_post?

Comment: I would suggest getting a firm understanding of how filters work in general. A filter is a modification to an existing set of responses from within the wordpress core's platform. 

You would put this piece of code into your functions.php located in your theme folder and it should work appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

For my solution first of all you need to decide the type of the template you want to overwrite.
So let's look at the following example: you want to overwrite/customize the single template for your custom post type.

1. First of all in your plugin create the custom folder and add the template to it.
2. Filter the single template using:

`add_filter( 'single_template', 'load_custom_template', 10, 3 );`

3. Add your plugin's template:

```
function load_custom_template( $template, $type, $templates ) {
    foreach( $templates as $tlp ) {
        if ( file_exists( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '{custom_folder}/' . $tlp ) ) {
            $template = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '{custom_folder}/' . $tlp;
        }
    }

    return $template;
}
```

*For different types of templates change the hook to `$type_template`

More information about the hook [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/type_template/)