# Is it possible not to load theme on a specific page in wordpress?

Tags: plugins, themes

I have a question about wordpress, I need the current theme installed on my wordpress not to be loaded on a certain page, is it possible?

What I want to do is create a bootstrap dashboard, and I don't want to load the default theme. The idea is to develop a dashboard via plugin and generate all the html, header, content, footer.

I thought about using "WP_USE_THEME" and using external files, but I need to use wordpress functions like: add_action, add_shortcode and etc.

I accept suggestions too !!! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a template file that gets loaded by the dashboard page? It is possible to create a template just like a theme template that actually lives in the plugin itself. That way, you can still call `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` and have full access to WP functionality, but not actually pull in whatever theme the site is using.

Here's an answer that shows how to do it: [How to add custom template in plugin?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/208181/how-to-add-custom-template-in-plugin#answer-208182)

Comment: I didn't know this filter, it's really what I want, thanks @WebElaine